# ios - Labels get duplicated when ViewController is called

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, custom-cell

I have a TableView with CoreData and Custom Cells which all works fine.

now when I select a cell to have its content edited and return from it, by just tapping the back button in a UINavigationController, I have something strange happen.

Please see the images what I mean. It seems that the updated UILabels are being placed on top of the old ones instead of being 'updated'??
Did I miss something??

You will see the difference in the top cell but it happens to all of them.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

**Edit: Added Code**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

customCell = [_mainTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (customCell == nil)
{
    customCell = [[MNCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    CGRect frameTitle;
    frameTitle = CGRectMake(20, 4, 195, 21);

    CGRect frameSummary;
    frameSummary = CGRectMake(20, 25, 250, 30);

    CGRect frameDate;
    frameDate = CGRectMake(200, 4, 100, 21);

    MNotes *mnotes = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Strings for Title and Summary
    titleString = mnotes.noteTitleString;
    summaryString = mnotes.mainNoteString;

    NSLog(@"TITLE STRING = %@", titleString);

    //Date
    SORelativeDateTransformer *relativeDateTransformer = [[SORelativeDateTransformer alloc] init];
    relativeDate = [relativeDateTransformer transformedValue:mnotes.createDate];

    customCell.noteTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frameTitle];
    customCell.noteTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    customCell.noteTitle.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
    customCell.noteTitle.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    customCell.noteTitle.textColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"274D70"];

    customCell.noteSummary = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:frameSummary];
    customCell.noteSummary.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    customCell.noteSummary.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
    customCell.noteSummary.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    customCell.noteDate = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frameDate];
    customCell.noteDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    customCell.noteDate.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
    customCell.noteDate.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    customCell.noteDate.textColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"274D70"]; //#274D70

}

customCell.noteTitle.text = titleString;
customCell.noteSummary.text = summaryString;
customCell.noteDate.text = relativeDate;

[customCell.contentView addSubview:customCell.noteTitle];
[customCell.contentView addSubview:customCell.noteSummary];
[customCell.contentView addSubview:customCell.noteDate];

 return customCell;
 }
```

Comment: please review my edited answer.

Comment: What is _mainTableView? Also see the new question in my response.

Comment: _mainTableView is the TableView inside a UIViewController - I have always had a warning come up if I use a normal tableView because it gets re-defined in this method, so this change has gotten rid of the warning and never caused any issues.

Comment: Is this a UITableViewController subclass that we are looking at?

Comment: No a UIViewController with a TableView added to it.

Comment: Ok I got it sussed!!! The whole problem was this: _customCell.noteTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; this would have meant that it would hide the label background and see what is behind there. Hence the Double ups:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved when you set a background color to your UILabel. I had it set to:

```
[UIColor clearColor];
```

This meant that I would keep seeing what happend to all previous entries.

So set it to any color e.g. `[UIColor blueColor];`

Answer (score 1):

UITableViews work by recycling cells.  When the table view requests a cell from its delegate, if there is an existing unused cell, it will use it.  Otherwise it will, allocate a new one.  You should only add labels when a new cell is allocated.  If it is instead recycled, you only want to set the text of the existing label.

---

Like this:

```
    customCell.noteDate.textColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"274D70"]; //#274D70

    [customCell.contentView addSubview:customCell.noteTitle];
    [customCell.contentView addSubview:customCell.noteSummary];
    [customCell.contentView addSubview:customCell.noteDate];
    // try adding this:
    customCell.contentView.autoresizesSubviews = false;
}

customCell.noteTitle.text = titleString;
customCell.noteSummary.text = summaryString;
customCell.noteDate.text = relativeDate;
```

Note: When instantiated, the cell's content view and might be size 0,0.  It could be resizing the subviews when it is given its real size.

---

This seemed strange... Why aren't you using the tableView that is calling the delegate? Like normal:

```
customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: I guess that my problem is that whatever I seem to put inside the block of code that you are referring to, seems to not be used in the part that I need.

Comment: See my other post as well.  Once it begins to recycle cells you will have different problems.

Answer (score 1):

This stuff needs to move out after the allocation block.:

```
MNotes *mnotes = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

//Strings for Title and Summary
titleString = mnotes.noteTitleString;
summaryString = mnotes.mainNoteString;

NSLog(@"TITLE STRING = %@", titleString);

//Date
SORelativeDateTransformer *relativeDateTransformer = [[SORelativeDateTransformer alloc] init];
relativeDate = [relativeDateTransformer transformedValue:mnotes.createDate];
```

This stuff really should go in your UITableViewCell subclass definition, but it can stay for now:

```
customCell.noteTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frameTitle];
customCell.noteTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
customCell.noteTitle.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
customCell.noteTitle.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
customCell.noteTitle.textColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"274D70"];

customCell.noteSummary = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:frameSummary];
customCell.noteSummary.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
customCell.noteSummary.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
customCell.noteSummary.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

customCell.noteDate = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frameDate];
customCell.noteDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
customCell.noteDate.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
customCell.noteDate.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
customCell.noteDate.textColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"274D70"]; //#274D70

[customCell.contentView addSubview:customCell.noteTitle];
[customCell.contentView addSubview:customCell.noteSummary];
[customCell.contentView addSubview:customCell.noteDate];
```

Answer (score 0):

What I suspect is that there is something wrong in your

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method implementation. Can you paste the code here.

What is obvious from the description is that, you are doing [cell addSubview:label] after recycling the cell. Hence, everytime the table's cell is reloaded, instead of just setting the label's text, you are adding a subview and then setting it.

What you should do is get the cell from [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identifier"], and only if cell is nil, perform addSubview. Otherwise, just set the subview's text

Comment: Yeah you are right, I am adding subviews - I have pasted the code

Comment: All the setting of text should happen outside if (customCell == nil) {
    customCell = [[MNCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
} block. Everything else related to setting layout, color etc should happen inside that block.

Comment: That does not seem to work, I get blank cells. the addSubView needs to be outside of that block to and in return I also need alloc & init outside of that block??

Comment: alloc and init should be inside that block. Lines like MNotes *mnotes = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

//Strings for Title and Summary
NSString *titleString = mnotes.noteTitleString; 
NSString *summaryString = mnotes.mainNoteString;

customCell.noteTitle.text = titleString;
customCell.noteSummary.text = summaryString;

all these are the only ones outside the block (before the return)

Comment: So I am doing what I think you are telling me - I have updated the code, but now my cells are empty.

Comment: Everything looks right, except that the following lines also shouls be outside the block.

MNotes *mnotes = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Strings for Title and Summary
    titleString = mnotes.noteTitleString;
    summaryString = mnotes.mainNoteString;

    NSLog(@"TITLE STRING = %@", titleString);

Comment: ok, I have that and it still is not working. I am also puzzled why you suggest that an alloc & init is within the block and the addSubView is outside - They seem to go hand in hand.